# $L^2$ convergence implies expected value of $f(X_n)$ converges to expected value of $f(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-continuity

This is from a second undergraduate course in probability.

Show if $X_n \overset{L^2}{\rightarrow} X$, $f$ a uniformly continuous and bounded function, then $\mathbb{E}f(X_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}f(X)$.

I suppose having $f$ bounded means the expected values are finite. Uniform continuity is used to prove that if $X_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} X$, then $g(X_n) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} g(X)$. And characteristic functions are uniformly continuous. But that material from the course doesn't seem helpful.

How do you start?

Comment: Can you show that $f(X_n) \overset{L^2}{\rightarrow} f(X)$ under your assumptions ?

Comment: Convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence in distribution. The uniform continuity hypothesis is irrelevant and so is the $p=2$. In fact any $p>0$ will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X_n\to^P X$ is sufficient. Let $\varepsilon >0$. There exists $\delta>0$ s.t. for all $x,y$ we have $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ so
$$\begin{aligned}
|E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]|&\stackrel{\textrm{Jensen}}\leq E[|f(X_n)-f(X)|]\\
&=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{|X_n-X|<\delta\}}|f(X_n)-f(X)|]+E[\mathbf{1}_{\{|X_n-X|\geq \delta\}}|f(X_n)-f(X)|]\\
&\leq \varepsilon P(|X_n-X|<\delta)+2\|f\|_\infty P(|X_n-X|\geq \delta)\end{aligned}$$
Since $X_n\to ^P X$ we have $\limsup_{n\to \infty}|E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]|\leq \varepsilon$.

Comment: (Note that this shows $f(X_n)\to^{L^1}f(X)$)

Comment: Then I suppose the trick is that if you don't start with $X_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} X$, then you use Chebyshev's theorem: $P(|X_n - X| > \delta) \leq \mathbb{E}(X_n - X)^2 / \delta^2$ (and $P(|X_n - X| > \delta) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$).

Comment: @johnsmith indeed a way to show directly that $X_n\to^{L^2}X\implies X_n\to^P X$ is using Chebyshev's.